# Is Datastax UUIDs a wrapper for java.util.UUID

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

If I don't encode `UUIDs.timeBased()` before inserting in a dataframe, I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for
>   java.util.UUID

So, instead of encoding, can I simply use `UUIDs.timeBased().toString()` before inserting into a dataframe (and subsequently Cassandra)?
And, if I need to parse a timestamp during a later data query, use `java.util.UUID.fromString(myUUIDSavedAsStringInCassandra)`?

Comment: Declare the column type as `timeuuid`

Comment: thanks....an exact duplicate indeed. Glad you found this

Comment: so YES it is a wrapper and YES it is OK to convert to String for dataframes (according to related question labeled above )